# How to set a command to execute at a certain time, using tkinter

Tags: tkinter, time, python-3.7

I'm making a timer program using Python.  I eventually want to run it on a Raspberry Pi.  It is for a dog sport called `'Flyball'`.
At present, my program uses a stopwatch class to display the time in seconds correct to 3 decimal places.  I can use the `'lap'` button to trigger an event which will display what the lap time is at the moment the lap button is pressed.

What I want to do is run a **'drag tree' of lights'**.  My timer begins at -6.0 seconds when I press 'Start'.  I have images of lights on my GUI and I would like them to trigger at set times:-

```
-3.0sec, 1st amber light on.
-2.0sec, 2nd amber light on.
-1.0sec, 3rd amber light on.
0.0sec, Green light on.
```

If I can get this to work, it won't be much more work to also include a beep noise when the lights come on.

I think I need some form of loop to keep checking the current stopwatch time and compare it to a set time like -3.0.
Can anybody give me any advice on how to do something like this?  Thank you in advance.

I can run the light tree on its own.  I use time.sleep() to space out the light timings (1 second apart), leave them on for 3 seconds when all lit up, then off again.
I do this by using itemconfig(state = 'normal') or itemconfig(state = 'hidden')
I get the same result using tk.after() also.

If I try to run this drag tree while the timer is running, the timer display will stop updating due to the sleep function.
If I try this again with the tk.after(), the 1st light will show but the rest of the sequence will not complete unless I press 'Stop' on the timer.

I've tried using if nextTime == -3.0 type of condition to trigger a simple print statement in the command prompt, but nothing appears.

This snippet of code is the Updater function in the stopwatch class.  It is what updates the time which is displayed on the screen.  Could I use the self.timer variable to trigger the lights?

def Updater(self):

```
self.totalTime = time.time() - self.startTime       
self.SetTime(self.totalTime)
self.timer = self.after(1,self.Updater)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `sleep` because it does exactly what it says: it puts the entire program to sleep. Instead, tkinter widgets have a method called `after` which can be used to run functions in the future.

In the following example I've created a function which prints "beep" in one second intervals, followed by "GO".

The `after` method accepts a time in milliseconds, a callable (eg: a reference to a function), and zero or more arguments to pass to that function.

```
def start_tree():
    print("beep")
    root.after(1000, print, "beep")
    root.after(2000, print, "beep")
    root.after(3000, print, "GO!")
```

It's important to realize that the call to `root.after` returns immediately. It isn't going to wait for the function to run. It simply puts the command on a queue for tkinter to run as soon as possible after the time has elapsed.

Comment: Thank you for your help Bryan.  Tkinter does behave much better using the after() statement.  I was able to create a variable called self.counter and stored the value of self.totalTime to 3 decimal places.  Any more and the countdown doesn't work.  I can now access the stopwatch time as it is running to trigger events.  I still have some working out to do with my classes and functions, but I think I'm on the right track now.